# .appendChild() is not a function when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, frontend

I am trying to transition from pure JavaScript to jQuery. I have a for loop that dynamically creates HTML elements with data from an API. Here is my old code:

```
recipeDiv = [];
recipeDiv[i] = document.createElement("div"); 
recipeDiv[i].setAttribute("class", "recipeBlock");
recipeDiv[i].appendChild(someElement);
```

However, when I transitioned to jQuery and used this instead

```
recipeDiv = [];
recipeDiv[i] = $("<div/>").addClass("recipeBlock");
recipeDiv[i].appendChild(someElement);
```

I get the following error: *recipeDiv[i].appendChild is not a function*

I know that .appendChild() isn't jQuery (JS), but shouldn't it still work? Even if I use the jQuery .append() function, I still get an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use $("<div>") instead of $("<div/>")

Comment: I think you can't mix normal JS functions with jQuery objects, since they are not part of jQuery's library of functions, append() does work tho https://jsfiddle.net/9ayh2598/

Comment: @Gerard I still get the same error... thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Gerard both versions will work fine. The `/` is completely irrelevant

Comment: A jQuery object has no method `appendChild()`. It's underlying dom element does. Use `append()`

Comment: @Lixus if I use .append() [object Object] gets outputted to the screen for some reason

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Lixus none of that comment makes sense

Comment: @charlietfl here is a minimal example of what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/5ozv80dh/

Comment: You are getting really confused mixing jQuery objects and native dom objects. Needs to be `$(recipeContainer).append(recipeDiv[i]);` since you are appending jQuery objects. Use one approach or the other but don't mix them  https://jsfiddle.net/5ozv80dh/1/

Comment: Also no need for the arrays to do this

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot, works great! I'm just confused as to why it needs to be `$(recipeContainer).append(recipeDiv)`... `recipeContainer` is a div stored in a variable so shouldn't I just be able to write `recipeContainer.append(recipeDiv)`?

Comment: Because there is a difference between a native dom element and a jQuery object wrapping a native element

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing yourself by inter-changing jQuery and DOM APIs. They cannot be used interchangeably. [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and [`$("<div />")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) returns the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object. `Element` object has the `appendChild` method and `jQuery` object has the `append` method.

As a good practice, I would suggest you choose between DOM APIs or jQuery, and stick to it. Here is a pure jQuery based solution to your problem

```js
var recipeContainer = $("<div/>")
  .addClass("recipeContainer")
  .appendTo("body");

var recipeDiv = [];
var likes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  //Create divs so you get a div for each recipe
  recipeDiv[i] = $("<div/>").addClass("recipeBlock");

  //Create divs to contain number of likes
  likes[i] = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("likes")
    .html("<b>Likes</b>");

  //Append likes blocks to recipe blocks
  recipeDiv[i].append(likes[i]);

  //Append recipe blocks to container
  recipeContainer.append(recipeDiv[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The arrays are also most likely not needed

Comment: I think so too. But the OP has them in his solution. Hence, just letting them be

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someElement is not created? Does the code need to be as follows?

```
recipeDiv = [];
var someElement = $("<div/>").addClass("recipeBlock");
recipeDiv[i].appendChild(someElement);
```

Comment: All elements are created. Check out this example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/5ozv80dh/2/