# Adding element with className to an other element with idName

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to add a created element li with a classname stored in an array, and I want to add this new element li with special classname to a static element with an id. I have an error appenChild is not a function. We are inside an JS object btw.
The console display the right thing, it shows me the li with the good classname, but i cant add it to the id stacks-icons.

I would like the final result to be : adding in my ul a new li with a classname i have chosen in the array icons.

here the HTML and JS :

```
<ul id="stacks-icons">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

And the JS ( variables in constructor )

```
    this.icons = ["fab fa-html5", "fab fa-css3"];
    this.iconsRow = $('#stacks-icons');
```

And the method

```
    let i = document.createElement('li');
    i.className = this.icons[1];
    this.iconsRow.appenChild(i);
    console.log(i);
```

Comment: Just a typo - it should be `appendChild` instead of `appenChild` in the method.

Comment: My bad, but the error is still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use querySelector to find DOM element and change appenChild to appendChild like this

```
let icons = ["fab fa-html5", "fab fa-css3"];
let ir = document.querySelector('#stacks-icons');
let i = document.createElement('li');
i.className = icons[1];
ir.appendChild(i);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works well. But why the Jquery selector did not find the id ?

Comment: This is because script is loading before element is created.

Comment: @eferdev that could be a reason, but I think this is because we are getting the element by jQuery method, so we should use jQuery method to modify the element as well. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086624/appendchild-is-not-a-function-when-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Use `appendChild` instead of `appenChild`. Also, use `document.querySelector` to select the dom element.

If you are using jQuery, then use `append()` instead of `appendChild()` because you are getting the element by a jQuery method so you should use jQuery method for appending as well. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086624/appendchild-is-not-a-function-when-using-jquery) for more info.

An example snippet is below -

```js
class Iconlist{
  constructor(){
    this.icons = ["fab fa-html5", "fab fa-css3"];
    this.iconsRow = $('#stacks-icons');
  }
  
  create(){
    let i = document.createElement('li');
    i.textContent = "Some text";
    i.className = this.icons[1];
    this.iconsRow.append(i);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

let mi = new Iconlist();
mi.create();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="stacks-icons">
  <li>ABC</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no method called `appendChild` if you select that element using `jQuery`. Jquery has `append` method by which you can append an element in your `ul`. I've added both ways(jquery and javascript) here in which you can achieve your goal. Here is the working example:

```js
var icons = ["fab fa-html5", "fab fa-css3"];

// 1st way using javascript
var ul = document.getElementById("stacks-icons");
let i = document.createElement('li');
i.className = icons[0];
i.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1st using javascript"));
ul.appendChild(i);


// 2nd way using jquery
var iconsRow = $('#stacks-icons');
let i1 = document.createElement('li');
i1.className = icons[1];
i1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2nd using jquery"));
iconsRow.append(i1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="stacks-icons">
    <li>Default</li>
</ul>
```